# how to put "link_to" under an entire card?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, card

I am a beginner in Ruby and I am in this doubt for many hours. how to put `"link_to"` under an entire card? I have this code:

```
<div class = "card-body">
     <h4> <% = link_to post.title, post%> </h4>

     <div class = "text-muted mb-2">
       <em> By <% = post.author%> (<% = l (post.created_at, format:: long)%>) </em>
     </div>

     <p> <% = post.body.truncate (220)%> </p>

     <p class = "text-muted"> <% = pluralize (post.comments.count, 'Comment')%> </p>
   </div>
```

and wanted the `"card-body"` class to function as the `"link_to"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a block to the [`link_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) method.

```
<%= link_to post do %>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4><%= post.title %></h4>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @LucasAraújo It should work. Can you share your latest code?